# Script HP Test and Attack system in Imacro

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a Script or Macro that simply checks my HP, and then attacks or heals. My macros work, I just can't get them to play with javascript. HP Test.iim Extracts the HP from the web page. I want to take that Extracted number and make it a variable. I'm new to scripting, maybe I can get some help.

New script based on code below (thanks for that)

```
ten = 1
while (ten = 1) {
iimPlay("Hunt/HP Test.iim");
var extract = iimGetLastExtract ();
var HP=extract.split("/")[0];
HP=parseInt(HP);
iimSet ( "HP", HP )
if ( HP >= 1 )
  {
iimPlay ("Hunt/Attack.iim")
  }
  else
  {
iimPlay ("Hunt/Heal.iim")
  }
}
```

IT Works! Thanks much, I've been working on that for a long time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
iimPlay("HP Test.iim"); 
var extract = iimGetLastExtract ();
iimSet ( "HP", extract )
if ( extract >= 1 )
  {
iimPlay ("Attack.iim")
  }
  else
  {
iimPlay ("Heal.iim")
  }
```

This code might not work but you will get an idea how the syntax works.

Edit: example of methods >>> http://jsfiddle.net/KRV5a/

Comment: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80520001 (NS_ERROR_FILE_UNRECOGNIZED_PATH) [nsILocalFile.initWithPath]"  nsresult: "0x80520001 (NS_ERROR_FILE_UNRECOGNIZED_PATH)"  location: "JS frame :: resource://imacros/utils.js :: <TOP_LEVEL> :: line 203"  data: no], line 199 (Error code: -991)

Comment: As far as I can tell that means HP Test.iim isn't running. according to one thing I read, I don't need the .iim in the JS. so I''m going to remove it and see if that works also I added at 0 to iimGetLastExtract (0). Should call all Extracts

Comment: Inside those .iim files has to be {{HP}} for script to store data into.

Comment: Okay trouble number one, I had all of the macros in a folder (the script was in there two, why I didn't think I needed the path) but I added the path and it works. . . now my problem is the if statement always goes to Heal. I think it has to do with how the HP is shown on the page 1113/1183. How much HP you have/ Your max HP. my question, is Java doing the division for me?. making my HP always negitive. or do I have my if statement backwards.

Comment: I'm also putting a loop in it. maybe there is a math Null for java

Comment: I added my HP Test to the question.

Comment: If the format of extracted text is number1/number2 then you have to use .split() method to split those numbers and parseInt() to convert to integer value. Then you can compare those numbers with zero

Comment: {{HP}} I missed you comment about that before. so that need to be in HP Test, Attack & Heal? or just HP Test. You mean set it. (SET {{HP}})?